# Ошибка exitCode = 1 при запуске Git (missing xcrun)

Tags: android-studio, git

При запуске Android Studio вылетает пуш-уведомление, что Git не может быть запущен, ошибка exitCode = 1:
`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools),
 missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

Подробности на скрине.
Как починить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написано же, `missing xcrun at: bla/bla/bla/xcrun`

Comment: как исправить-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наши зарубежные товарищи [советуют](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/) набрать в терминале команду
`xcode-select --install`

Она скачает и установит *xcode developer tools*, что решит проблему.

Так же, некоторым, у кого *xcode developer tools* уже установлены помогает команда
`xcode-select --reset`